# Selected listBox row columns referenced by listBox column head name instead of column index number

Tags: ms-access, vba

How do I do this? I have a quite complex `listBox`, containing 12 columns in total and want to fill out some `textBox` fields in my form upon `listBox_Click()`.

At the moment I do it such that:

```
With Me
    .txtBox1 = Me.lstBox.Column(0)
    .txtBox2 = Me.lstBox.Column(1)
    .txtBox3 = Me.lstBox.Column(5)
    .txtBox4 = Me.lstBox.Column(10)
End With
```

However, this can be very confusing when I add/remove a specific column from the `listBox`. VBA would not let me reference the `Column` in this way:

```
Me.txtBox1 = Me.lstBox.Column("Price")
```

Where `"Price"` is basically the `Column header` that displays in my `lstBox`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Or rather, if you insist, you will first have to create a VBA Collection with the coloumn name as key and the index as value. Then you can do like this:

```
Me!txtBox1.Value = Me!lstBox.Column(CollectionOfColumns("Price"))
```

Or, if the series of columns is fixed, you can create an Enum and use:

```
Me!txtBox1.Value = Me!lstBox.Column(EnumOfColumns.Price)
```

Comment: I saw some VBA code on other forms using `.Control.Name` and `.Controls.Name`. I didn't quite get the idea of how it works though. Could it be one of the solutions?

Comment: I guess not. But if you (temporarly) set Me!lstBox.ColumnHeads = True   you can retrieve the column heads from row zero:   ColumnHeadN = Me!lstBox.Column(N, 0)

Comment: That is very helpful indeed, didn't know about that, thanks! Got it sorted now =).